# I need the Lua math library in NodeMCU

Tags: algorithm, math, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I need to perform log calculations for a thermistor, however the Lua math library (`math.log`) doesn't seem to be implemented, or I'm doing something wrong. It's not a module on NodeMCU-build.com or in the docs, either.

Any ideas/suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Have you tried if it's actually there, or are you just assuming that because it's not in the documentation?

Comment: No, it's not there...  I tried running code, and then I looked at the documentation, and then I searched for documentation regarding math functions in the NodeMCU firmware, and found none except for questions like my own regarding powers, and people highlighting that they could use x ^ n rather than math,pwr().

Comment: It ain't there: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/lua-developer-faq/#how-is-nodemcu-lua-different-to-standard-lua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local function log(x)
   assert(x > 0)
   local a, b, c, d, e, f = x < 1 and x or 1/x, 0, 0, 1, 1
   repeat
      repeat
         c, d, e, f = c + d, b * d / e, e + 1, c
      until c == f
      b, c, d, e, f = b + 1 - a * c, 0, 1, 1, b
   until b <= f
   return a == x and -f or f
end

local function log10(x)
   return log(x) / 2.3025850929940459
end
```

Comment: That's a lot simpler than I imagined...  Thanks a lot!  